# Get list of private videos from channel

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I want to get list of private videos in my channel.
I can list public videos (`/search?` or `/playlistItems?` queries), but cannot find a way to list the private ones.

I tried listing the *uploads* playlist, but it returns only public videos (all my videos are private, excepting one).

I've successfully done OAuth authentication/authorization, but cannot understand how to use this key `4/5AEHB....AB` in a query.

Comment: Alexey, please specify your programming environment. Do bear in mind that the YouTube Data API is actually used within many kinds of environments, from bare command line HTTPS method calls using e.g. `wget` or `curl`, to involved ones like `Python`, `Java`, etc., etc.

Comment: Is it matters? I use simple browser and query youtube with https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/

Comment: It does, because for you to obtain private data you'll have to pass on a valid access token to the API endpoint in question.

Comment: If playing within a browser, I'd recommend you to use a better tool than plain URL invocations: [Google Developers 
OAuth 2.0 Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/).

Comment: By the way, the OAuth 2.0 protocol does entail *quite a few kinds of keys*. See the official doc [OAuth 2.0 for Mobile & Desktop Apps](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/installed-apps). Your post doesn't mention what kind of key *your key* is.

Comment: OAuth 2.0 playground is great! I see, how oauth token transforms to http headers :) Thanks!
But anywhere I cant list my private videos. Public videos is found ok, but not private.

Comment: But *is that your own channel* you're taking about? If it's not, then private data is private.

Comment: In any case, depending of your actual programming environment, I would recommend to use one of Google's APIs client libraries (that are available for a pletora of modern programming languages). Implementing by hand [the refreshing of access tokens](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/installed-apps#offline) can be tedious at times. (These tokens are short-lived!)

Comment: Its my channel, of course, and I can see all videos in browser, but I want to get list of videos in my application.

Comment: It's likely that I'll could help your: back to my initial question: which is your programming environment?

Comment: Its a python with flask webserver, so I would use google-api-python-client or something like that.

Comment: Then it may come of use to have a look at the official [Python Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/quickstart/python). You wouldn't then have to pass on manually to the API those access tokens. The client library will make your life much more bearable.

Comment: Forgot to mention that Google made public quite a few [API samples](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/). Clone that repo and have a look at the source code in the `python` directory. The client library [is also on Github](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client).

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution: query is

```
/youtube/v3/search?part=id&forMine=true&maxResults=25&type=video
```

with OAuth authorization and additional http-header

```
Authorization: Bearer [access token]
```

It list all videos, including private videos.

Comment: The doc that I quoted above has the section [HTTP GET examples](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/installed-apps#http-get-examples) that specifies precisely that behavior.

Comment: I cant find it by myself :) Thank you for help :)

Comment: Yes, the playground may help you understand   how things work. But, otherwise, programming for production (i.e. not for one's only use in private) implies programming using the official documentation, thus programming against the official specifications. Isn't my statement right?

Comment: Of course I would not use direct http queries in my app in production, but I want to see, how libraries work, so I try to construct queries with simple browser (or with playground, great thing) and see what happened.